# How to change color in animation?

Tags: animation, color

I press 'I' for inserting a keyframe, but couldn't find 'color keyframe' in menu.
There are only 'loc','scale','rot'
If I change object's color in a certain frame, then the color of object is changed too over all frames.
Then how can I change color in amimation?

Comment: You needto plug your 2 colors in a Mix shader and keyframe the Mix factor value so that it goes from a color to another one

Comment: Hover the the object color property and press `I`

Comment: @Thank you for answer. But how can I connect mix factor and keyframe?

Answer (score 2):

Hover the the *Object Color* property in the properties window and press <kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I didn't know that. But it is available in viewport display.
I want to change color in render. I couldn't find the toggle button to be changed to diamond in 'surface' menu

Answer (score 2):

I did something like what Mr. Ramos did, (though I'm not as good as him). However, I thought that perhaps seeing what this creates in the Graph Editor would help you.

As you can see, Red, Green, Blue, as well as Alpha keys are created, and each can be changed at any frame, creating a new key frame.
[image: Frame 1 of 60]
[image: Frame 60 of 60]

Comment: I did it, thanks to you~ It was the point that putting cursor over the color box on the left side of 'Base Color' and press 'I'

Answer (score 2):

In the *Shader Editor* you can create some keyframes on a *Mix Shader*. Plug 2 colors into the sockets of a *Mix Shader*. at frame 1 put the *Mix Shader* factor at 0, put your mouse cursor over it and press <kbd>i</kbd> to create your first keyframe, the value becomes green, it means it has saved the value, it will also create a yellow dot in the *Dopesheet*. Then at frame 20 put the *Mix Shader* factor at 1, put your mouse cursor over it and press <kbd>i</kbd>. Now if you play the animation the color will gradually change from color 1 to color 2. If you want the color to change suddenly, at frame 19 just create a keyframe on the *Mix Shader* with the factor at 0, so frame 19 to frame 20 the factor will jump from 0 to 1.

[image]

Comment: Really thank you for helping. I solved it :)